# Howler.js - Fire events when sound finishes fading or volume has changed

Tags: javascript, howler.js

How can I fire the event sound.stop() automatically when fading of the sound has finished(fade target volume = 0.3) and also show an alert popup window as soon as the volume is 0.6?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/goldfire/howler.js/master/src/howler.core.js"></script>
<button onclick="Play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="StartFade()">Fade</button>

<script>
var sound = new Howl({
src: ['https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/rave_digger.webm']});

function Play() sound.play();
function StartFade() sound.fade(1, 0.3, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .fade() method fires a "fade" event when completed. You can attach a listener to the sound object

```
sound.on('fade', function(){
  console.log('#Faded!!');
});
```

Alternately, you could set the onFade() method when you create the new Howl.

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/rave_digger.webm'],
  onFade: function(){
    //stuff goes here!
  }

});
```

For showing an alert when volume hits 0.6, you could chain your call backs so the first fade method is actually just from 1 to 0.6, then within the event listener, pop up the alert , then make a new fade from 0.6 to 0.3

Using the onFade() and onVolume() methods, you could also write it like this, though it would raise this alert anytime the volume was set to 0.6, fade or not.

```
onVolume: function(){
  if (this.volume == 0.6)
    alert("Volume is currently 0.6!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the functions onfade() and onvolume()?
They are still valid functions?

Comment: Yes! I forgot about those. Going to add that into my answer.